# word.interop print maindocument from mail merge

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, ms-office, office-interop

I created a mail merge with `Interop.Word` from a .doc file.

It works fine, loads the data from a specified datasource and I can view the filled-in data with the method `wDoc.MailMerge.EditMainDocument();`

But I don't want to open it only, but to I want to print out the MainDocument, which means I want to print 15 pages, if there are 15 entries in my mailmerge-datasource.

When I perofrm wDoc.PrintOut my basic-Doc-File is printed out, without filled in data!

Is this possible, and how?

Here my code so far:

```
Application wApp = new Application();
Document wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(ref oFile, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
wDoc.Activate();
wApp.ActivePrinter = "TestPrinter";

wDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(wDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.Name, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
wDoc.MailMerge.Execute(ref missing);

wDoc.MailMerge.EditMainDocument();
wDoc.MailMerge.Execute(ref missing);

wDoc.PrintOut(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
wDoc.Close(ref saveOptionsObject, ref missing, ref missing);
wApp.Quit(ref saveOptionsObject, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send your document to the printer in different way. I'm trying to convert VBA code to C# below but some other adjustments could be required.

```
//before you run .Execute method try to set the followings:
wDoc.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToPrinter; // vba constant
wDoc.MailMerge.SuppressBlankLines = True; 
wDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord; //vba constant
wDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord; //vba constant
//and now you need to .Execute mailmerge
wDoc.MailMerge.Execute(ref missing); //or try with False parameter inside ()
```

**EDIT (tested for C#, thanks to Karl):**

```
// ...OpenDataSource
wDoc.MailMerge.Destination = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdMailMergeDestination.wdSendToPrinter;
wDoc.MailMerge.SuppressBlankLines = true;
wDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.FirstRecord = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdMailMergeDefaultRecord.wdDefaultFirstRecord;
wDoc.MailMerge.DataSource.LastRecord = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdMailMergeDefaultRecord.wdDefaultLastRecord;
wDoc.MailMerge.Execute(ref missing);
// wDoc.Close...
```

Comment: Thank you!
I changed a view minor things and it works like a charm